Finding the no. of students who play both football and volleyball from a class of $18$ given that $10$ can play football and $14$ can play volleyball
Of the $18$ students in the class, $10$ can play football and $14$ can play volleyball. Let the number of students who play both football and volleyball be $N$. What is the sum of all values ​​in $N$?
My answer is $N=10+14-18=6$ .But the original answer is $6+7+8+9+10=40$. I don't understand anything. How can this be possible? If $10$ students play both football and volleyball, the remaining $8$ students have to play only volleyball. This means $18$ students play volleyball. I'm very confused.

Hint: Some student may play none.

Please, use descriptive titles. "What am I missing?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

$N$ is not a set, it is a number

I take it to mean: What is the sum of all possible values of $N$? That is: it is possible that only six students can play both, and this is indeed the smallest number possible. But it's also possible that every student who can play football can also play volleyball (but not vice versa). So which values of $N$ are possible?

I do not understand

If $10$ students play both football and volleyball, the remaining $8$ students have to play only volleyball. This means $10+8=18>14$ students play volleyball.

@user As Anne Bauval mentioned above, some students may play neither.  The correct situation is "if 10 play both and 14 play volleyball, then 4 play only volleyball and 4 play none"

@BrianMoehring But the above answer does not tell anything about this point.

@BrianMoehring Thank you.


As you see $R$ is the number of students may play none.$$(10-N) + \ N + \ (14-N )+ \ R \ =18\\24-N +R =18\\R=0 \to 24-N=18 \to N=6\\R=1 \to 24-N+1=18 \to N=7\\\vdots$$

Based on the answer you gave, it's asking for the sum of all the possible values of $N$. I think the easiest way to get a full image of the whole situation is by making a table. In this case you have something like the table below, where $F$ and $N$ are the number of students who play football and volleyball respectively with $F'$ and $N'$ the amount of students not playing the corresponding sports.
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{} & \textbf{F} & \textbf{F'} & \textbf{Total}\\
\hline
\textbf{V} & N & a & 14 \\
\hline
\textbf{V'} & b & c & 4 \\
\hline
\textbf{Total} & 10 & 8 & 18 \\
\hline
\end{array}
I think where you had misunderstanding as one of the comments suggests, is that you assumed there are no students who do neither.
Purely from the table, it's quite easy come to the following equations:
\begin{align}
& N+a=14 &
& b+c=4 &
& N+b = 10 &
& a+c = 8 &
\end{align}
Then adding some equations we get
\begin{align}
& 2N+a+b=24 &
& a+b+2c=12 &
\end{align}
From which it follows that $N-c=6$ so $c=N-6$. Then from the second row of the table, we see that $0\leq c \leq 4$ so in particular $0 \leq N-6\leq 4$ and $6 \leq N \leq 10$, which gives the solutions $N=6,7,8,9,10$ and their sum is 40.

The question is asking the sum of ALL POSSIBLE VALUES OF N. This means that 6 is not the only answer available. We can also consider that some students play neither sport. This means that if everyone plays, you get:
$10-N+N+14-N=18; N=6$
. If one person doesn't play, the right side of the equation is 17, and N=7. This will continue until it's 14, because 14 people play volleyball, and it can't be less.
Therefore, $10-N+N+14-N=14; N=10.$ Therefore, $6+7+8+9+10=40$
